# Unable to bulk upsert using sequelize

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using `sequelize(5.21.6)` with `sqlite3(^4.1.1)`.

I have `two models A and B` with `many to many relation` between them.

I want to bulk insert or update into the pivot table.

To achieve this I created a third model for the pivot table, lets call it `AB`.

So here is how I am trying to bulk `upsert` into pivot table.

```
db.AB.bulkCreate([array of values], {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['aId', 'bId', 'updatedAt']
});
```

The error which I get:

```
{ Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ")": syntax error
   [0]      errno: 1,
   [0]      code: 'SQLITE_ERROR', 
   [0]      sql: INSERT INTO `AB` (`id`,`aId`,`bId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (19,1,1,'example',\'2020-04-15 15:18:59.000 +00:00\',\'2030-04-15 15:18:59.000 +00:00\'),(20,2,2,\'2030-04-15 15:19:49.000 +00:00\',\'2030-04-15 15:19:49.000 +00:00\') ON CONFLICT () DO UPDATE SET `aId`=EXCLUDED.`aId`, `bId`=EXCLUDED.`bId`,`updatedAt`=EXCLUDED.`updatedAt`;'
}
```

My `AB model` definition:

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const AB = sequelize.define('AB', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    aId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    bId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  AB.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    AB.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'aId' });
    AB.belongsTo(models.B, { foreignKey: 'bId' });
  };
  return AB;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that sqlite3 supports multiple value series in an insert SQL command?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do the same for model A.

Comment: I think you have to update your sequelize version to 6 because i also faced same error and i have to update my `sequelize version 5.21.3 to 6.5.3`